# Print grails test-app failures to console

Tags: grails, junit, spock

There have been several questions about this on SO already, but none of the answers was satisfactory. I am doing test-driven grails development. However, because STS keeps crashing, I can't use it to run the unit tests and run them using "grails test-app" on the command line instead. This is fine, but when a test fails, it just won't print the REASON for the failure to the console. Using -echoOut and -echoErr as suggested in other threads does *not* help, this will only print stuff that was logged or printed during the test, but not the JUnit or Spock reason of failure. So currently, I always have to wait for the HTML to be generated and then find the failure in my browser and this reallly slows me down. I will accept any solution, no matter how hacky (i.e. hacking it into the grails source and recompiling it would be fine with me!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this...

```
grails test-app -echoOut -echoErr Something.testMain ; cat ./target/test-reports/plain/TEST-integration-integration-SomethingTests.txt
```

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot I had been toying around with the plain text files already :( That's only a little bit better because I still have to wait for grails to shut down completely which is a couple of seconds after the actual failure.

Comment: In Unix, `tail -f ./target/test-reports/plain/TEST-integration-integration-SomethingTests.txt & && grails test-app -echoOut -echoErr Something.testMain` should work.

Comment: That's not a bad idea, although still cumbersome. This might be solved in 2.0: "* Unit test scaffolding and enhanced unit test output in the console " http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-1-4-is-now-Grails-2-0-td3627931.html